# How to output only random xx% of query output records in Redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Is there a way to output only a percentage of the total number of output records in Redshift, when you don't know the number of records returned?

Let's say the output of the query will be 1000 records. You just want to select randomly 60% of it... So that will be 600 records in this case.

If I knew that the output is always 1000, then I would use LIMIT 600. But I don't know how many records will be returned, and I want it to be variable..

Any ideas?

PS: Tried to use LIMIT (0.6*COUNT(*)) and it didn't work.. The error was that "LIMIT doesn't take a variable"

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need an *exact* number of records but about 60%, then I would recommend:

```
where random() <= 0.6
```

If you do need an exact number, then:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by random()) as seqnum,
             count(*) over () as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 0.6 * cnt;
```

Comment: do you mean just add the where random() above to the query?? (YES, I need a percentage of total number of returned records, and not an exact number)

Comment: @ZelelB . . . Then use the first version.  It should be faster than attempting to sort the data.

Comment: I didn't understand the difference somehow... in both you're using 0.6 (so 60%) where is the exact number? Could you provide an example please? Sorry for being slow :D

Comment: `where random() <= 0.6` will generate a random number for each row. Assuming that the random numbers are evenly distributed, the statement will evaluate to `TRUE` 60% of the time. Similarly, you could use `ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 10` if you just want 10 random rows.